# tsql, picking out value-pairs

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have a column that has the following data:

PersonId="315618" LetterId="43" MailingGroupId="1" EntityId="551723" trackedObjectId="9538" EmailAddress="myemailaddy@addy.com"

Is there any good, clean tsql syntax to grab the 551723 (the value associated with EntityId).  The combination of Substring and Patindex I'm using seems quite unwieldy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That strings looks just like an XML attribute list for an element, so you can wrap it into an XML element and use xpath:

```
declare @t table (t nvarchar(max));
insert into @t (t) values (
    N'PersonId="315618" LetterId="43" MailingGroupId="1" 
     EntityId="551723" trackedObjectId="9538" 
     EmailAddress="myemailaddy@addy.com"');


with xte as (
    select cast(N'<x '+t+N'/>' as xml) as x from @t)
select 
    n.value(N'@PersonId', N'int') as PersonId
    , n.value(N'@LetterId', N'int') as LetterId
    , n.value(N'@EntityId', N'int') as EntityId 
    , n.value(N'@EmailAddress', N'varchar(256)') as EmailAddress
    from xte
    cross apply x.nodes(N'/x') t(n);
```

Whether this is better or worse that string manipulation depends on a variety of factors, not least the size of the string and number of records to parse. I preffer the simple and clean xpath syntax over char index based manipulation (the code is much more maintainable).

Comment: Great idea Remus, I agree with you.

Answer (score 3):

If that's the text in the column, then you're going to have to use substring at some stage.

```
 declare @l_debug varchar(1000)
select @l_debug = 'PersonId="315618" LetterId="43" MailingGroupId="1" EntityId="551723" trackedObjectId="9538" EmailAddress="myemailaddy@addy.com"'

select  substring(@l_debug, patindex('%EntityId="%', @l_debug)+ 10, 6)
```

If you don't know how long EntityID could be, then you'll need to get the patindex of the next double-quote after EntityID="

```
declare @l_debug varchar(1000), @l_sub varchar(100), @l_index2 numeric
select @l_debug = 'PersonId="315618" LetterId="43" MailingGroupId="1" EntityId="551723" trackedObjectId="9538" EmailAddress="myemailaddy@addy.com"'

select @l_sub = substring(@l_debug, patindex('%EntityId="%', @l_debug)+ 10 /*length of "entityid=""*/, char_length(@l_debug))


select  @l_index2 =  patindex('%"%', @l_sub)

select substring(@l_debug, patindex('%EntityId="%', @l_debug)+ 10, @l_index2 -1)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you possibly can, break out your data. Either normalize your tables or store XML in the column (with an XML data type) instead of name, value pairs. You'll then be able to use the full power and speed of SQL Server, or at least be able to issue XPath queries (assuming a relatively recent version of SQL Server).

I know this probably won't help you in the short term, but it's a goal to work towards. :)

Comment: That's how I build my tables, but unfortuantely not everyone else does :)

Comment: I still believe redesign is the only way to go. Would you fail to refactor bad code in the application? This is simply bad design and needs to be refactored.

Comment: It sounds like he may not have a choice. It could be a table created by a third-party app, for instance. Heavy sigh.

Comment: Although if it doesn't need to be real-time, I might consider copying the database on a periodic basis to a normalized version.

Answer (score 0):

```
Substring(

Substring(EventArguments,PATINDEX('%EntityId%', EventArguments)+10,10),0, 
PATINDEX('%"%', Substring(EventArguments,
PATINDEX('%EntityId%', EventArguments)+10,10))

)
```